# Generate Laravel HTML for Image in Laravel Way

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Here is the Link generation in Laravel way

```
{{ HTML::link('http://test.com', 'testing')}}
```

which is alternative for

```
<a href="http://test.com">testing</a>
```

And Here is the Image Generation in Laravel way

```
{{ HTML::image('img/picture.jpg', 'a picture', array('class' => 'thumb')) }}
```

Which is alternative for

**But How can i create**

```
<a href="http://your.url/img/picture.jpg">
<img src="http://your.url/img/picture.jpg" class="thumb" alt="a picture">
</a>
```

So That i can generate a HTML Link which has Image inside it, instead of having only the text inside it.

How can i do this ?

**Update :**

```
$img='a.jpg';
<a href="assets/uploads/prsdk/" target="_blank">{{ HTML::image('assets/uploads/prsdk/'.$img, 'alt', array( 'width' => 35, 'height' => 35 )) }}</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

For Static Link

```
<a href="#"><img src={{asset('img/logo.png')}} alt="Logo"></a>
```

For Dynamic Link

```
<a href="{{URL::to('/')}}"><img src={{asset('img/logo.png')}} alt="Logo"></a>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it would be helpful if i use ** {{ HTML::link('http://test.com', 'testing')}}** this way for href too

Answer (score 1):

You could just write the tag yourself and in href/src you can use the laravel `route('route.name')` and `asset('img_path/img_name.png')`.

But if you still want to achieve that using `HTML` class, the following code will work.

```
{{ html_entity_decode(HTML::link('test.com',HTML::image('img/picture', 'a picture', array('class' => 'thumb')))) }}
```

Comment: Can i pass dynamic variable to the link and the image ??

Comment: Yes! you can pass dynamic variable as well.

Comment: I have update the question with dynamic variable, Can you modify the code accordingly,

Comment: Another issue is i have index.php in the url, once i use the way you suggested the url forming is domain.com/img/index.php/a.jpg

Comment: Actually the href should have assets/upload/prsdk/$img